# How can I get same value in windows and web project with ToString() function?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 2 projects. One of them with C# windows and another with C# WCF Service. But both of them use one dll that is with C# class library project. in this DLL I have following row :

```
string tmpStr = 104.2677519379845.ToString();
```

in windows it returns :

> 104.267751937985

but in Web it returns :

> 104.267751937984

Comment: Can you post the method that returns the string and the method/code where you use this string and show it on the UI?

Comment: Are you running this on different machines with different processors? Note your value is a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Build options of your project. For "x86" or "Any CPU" with "Prefer 32-bit" you will get "104.267751937984". Otherwise you will get "104.267751937985".

If you will work on Decimal (`104.2677519379845M.ToString()`) then you will get the correct value (in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I chose Decimal instead of Double and test for 3 days with different values and it work correct.